# Android TabHost come over softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-tabhost, android-softkeyboard

My problem is that when I click on chatting view's edittext then softkeyoboard pushes tab view and edittext both. This should only push edittext with stable header at top. For details below is problem screen shot. I have googled and  used

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"

etc but this does not seems to work.

[image: Problem Image]

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file, set this property in your base tabbar activity,

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.demo.tabbar.BaseTabbarActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
```

And in your particular fragment class, add following lines,

```
        getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_MASK_ADJUST);
```

I had resolved my same tabbar issue by this code. Hope, this may help you.